# Laravel s3 multiple buckets

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Laravel application needs to manipulate files present in multiple buckets simultaneously into a single session. So, I couldn't find a way to change several times the current bucket, since my `.env` file is like this:

```
S3_KEY='MY-KEY'
S3_SECRET='MySeCret'
S3_REGION='us-east-1'
S3_BUCKET='my-first-used-bucket'
```

I found somewhere that I could do this:

```
Config::set('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket', 'another-bucket');
```

but It works only once. What I need is something like:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('/bucket-name/path/filename.jpg', $file, 'public');
```

Where `/bucket-name/` could be any bucket that I already create. What can I do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean only works once? `Config::set('foo', 'bar'); Config::set('foo', 'baz'); echo Config::get('foo'); // baz` will work...

Comment: @BenSwinburne It works like a first configuration. So, if I set a bucket using Config::set, it works, the files will be stored into the correct location, but if I try to change the bucket later, using the same method, the current bucket stills the same and the files will be stored into the first bucket.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You are correct in that  `Config::set();` only works once per request. My estimation is that this is done intentionally to stop the kind of thing you are attempting to do in your code example.

In config/filesystems.php you can list any number of "disks". These are locations of your file repositories. It looks like so:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'ftp' => [
        'driver'   => 'ftp',
        'host'     => 'ftp.example.com',
        'username' => 'your-username',
        'password' => 'your-password',

        // Optional FTP Settings...
        // 'port'     => 21,
        // 'root'     => '',
        // 'passive'  => true,
        // 'ssl'      => true,
        // 'timeout'  => 30,
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('S3_KEY',''),
        'secret' => env('S3_SECRET',''),
        'region' => env('S3_REGION',''),
        'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET',''),
    ],
]
```

#### The Solution

The solution is to create a new disk of the extra buckets you want to use. ***Treat your buckets like different disks.***

**Note:** The user that the S3_Key belongs to needs to have permissions to perform your required actions on the S3 buckets you are setting up as additional 'disks'.

```
'disks' => [

    //All your other 'disks'
    ...

    //My default bucket details.
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('S3_KEY',''),
        'secret' => env('S3_SECRET',''),
        'region' => env('S3_REGION',''),
        'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET',''),
    ],

    's3MyOtherBucketName' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('S3_KEY',''),
        'secret' => env('S3_SECRET',''),
        'region' => env('S3_REGION',''),
        'bucket' => 'myOtherBucketName',
    ],

    's3YetAnotherBucketName' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('S3_KEY',''),
        'secret' => env('S3_SECRET',''),
        'region' => env('S3_REGION',''),
        'bucket' => 'yetAnotherBucketName',
    ],
]
```

Then whenever you want to access the bucket of your choice call it like so:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, $data);
Storage::disk('s3MyOtherBucketName')->put($anotherFileName, $moreData);
Storage::disk('s3YetAnotherBucketName')->put($yetAnotherFileName, $evenMoreData);
```

Comment: the most elegant way to deal with multiple s3 buckets. Thanks

Comment: what if the bucket is the only one that's different but all of it has the same key, secret, and region? isn't this a redundant code?

Comment: There are a lot of good reasons to have redundant code, especially when the repeated lines are near each other so other developers can notice the duplication. This amount of redundancy shouldn't set off any alarm bells

Comment: Yikes! This is even simpler. +1 that it doesn't break the default key.

Answer (score 31):

If you have dynamic buckets you also can create a new instance like this:

```
$storage = Storage::createS3Driver([
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key'    => 'your-key',
    'secret' => 'your-secret',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'bucket' => $bucketName,
]);

$storage->put('path/to/file.png', $content);
```

Comment: So could you use this as sort of a separator for different 'customers' or 'clients' ? Would the duplicate not be stored, or would it store duplicates? How would you check against an existing s3 'bucket'?

Answer (score 15):

You can add the buckets to the filesystems config like so:

```
'disks' => [
    's3' => [
        'bucket1' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_BUCKET1_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_BUCKET1_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_BUCKET1_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET1_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_BUCKET1_URL'),
        ],
        'bucket2' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_BUCKET2_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_BUCKET2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_BUCKET2_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET2_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_BUCKET2_URL'),
        ],
    ],
],
```

Then you can access the server using the following:

```
\Storage::disk('s3.bucket1')->put('path/to/file.png', $content);
```

Comment: Ouch! Simple, smooth and straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class for myself and named it `StorageProxy`. You can [find it here](https://gist.github.com/erfansahaf/68544076d80baa9939a3300d21e15df9).

Let's say you want to work with multiple drivers, one of which is an S3-Compatible Object Storage but you may need to change the storage driver on-the-fly, `local` for example. No problem,  the `StorageProxy` deals with it! (similar to `mc` - MinIO Client)

**Usage**:

```php
StorageProxy::touch(?string $disk, ?string $bucket)->{everyStorageMethod}();
```

If no disk is specified, it uses the `default` disk (it's defined in `filesystem.php`).

**Example**:

For the `local` driver our file exists in `images/sample.jpg`

For `s3` driver our file exists in `images` bucket with the name of `sample.jpg`

Our `filesystem.php` file should look like this:

```
'localhost' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path('/'),
],

'DO' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    // No need to specify the `bucket` property here
],
```

Since it's a proxy class, all `Storage` methods are available in *StorageProxy* too. Also, you don't need to remove the bucket name from the file path for `s3` disks.

```php
// For local disk
$disk = 'localhost';
StorageProxy::touch($disk)->exists("images/sample.jpg"); // true

// For S3 disk
$disk = 'DO';
StorageProxy::touch($disk)->exists("images/sample.jpg"); // true
StorageProxy::touch($disk, "images")->exists("images/sample.jpg"); // true
StorageProxy::touch($disk, "images")->bucketDetection(false)->exists("images/sample.jpg"); // false - the file path is considered as images/images/sample.jpg 
StorageProxy::touch($disk, "images")->exists("sample.jpg"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an on-Demand Filesystem Disk
Andrew Brown contributed an on-demand filesystem disk, which allows you to configure a filesystem disk on-the-fly:

```php
// String uses the local driver
Storage::build(storage_path('logs'));
 
// Full control over configuration
Storage::build([
    'driver'     => 'local',
    'root'       => 'my-custom-path',
    'url'        => 'my-custom-url',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]);
```